# "USB Storage" Encryption

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, encryption, samsung-galaxy-note

Samsung phones, Galaxy Note running ICS 4.0.3 in particular has System Storage, USB Storage, and SD Card.
I wanted to know if I encrypt my device by going to Settings - Security - Encrypt Device.  Will it encrypt the "USB Storage" as well aside from the System Storage?